# Cozyroc 837 mapping Loop issue

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, edi, x12

I have successfully loaded x12 835 formatted data into sql server 2014 using Cozyroc and SSIS.  I am having an issue with creating a mapping for an 837 because of the loops involved.  How do you handle the loops in the mapping file?  I had no problem creating a mapping file for an 835 using the segments and fields tags, but I'm not sure of the syntax to handle the loops in an 837.

**Sample parsed x12 XML-**

```
  <Loop LoopId="1000A" Name="SUBMITTER NAME">
        <NM1>
          <!--Entity Identifier Code-->
         <NM101>
            <!--Submitter-->
         </NM101>
          <!--Entity Type Qualifier-->
          <NM102>
            <!--Non-Person Entity-->
          </NM102>
          <!--Name Last or Organization Name-->
          <NM103></NM103>
          <NM104 />
          <NM105 />
          <NM106 />
          <NM107 />
          <!--Identification Code Qualifier-->
          <NM108>
            <!--Electronic Transmitter Identification Number (ETIN)-->
          </NM108>
         <NM109 />
        </NM1>


        <PER>
          <!--Contact Function Code-->
          <PER01>
            <!--Information Contact-->
          </PER01>
           <!--Name-->
          <PER02></PER02>
          <!--Communication Number Qualifier-->
          <PER03>
            <!--Telephone-->
          </PER03>
          <!--Communication Number-->
          <PER04></PER04>
          <!--Communication Number Qualifier-->
          <PER05>
            <!--Facsimile-->
          </PER05>
          <!--Communication Number-->
          <PER06></PER06>
        </PER>

      </Loop>
```

**837 config (not working)-**

```
    <medi:segment loopID ="1000A" segcode="NM1" xmltag="SUBMITTER NAME">

      <medi:field xmltag="NM101"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM102"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM103"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM104"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM105"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM106"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM107"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM108"/>
      <medi:field xmltag="NM109"/>


      <medi:segment segcode="PER" xmltag="PER">
        <medi:field xmltag="PER01"/>
        <medi:field xmltag="PER02"/>
        <medi:field xmltag="PER03"/>
        <medi:field xmltag="PER04"/>
        <medi:field xmltag="PER05"/>
        <medi:field xmltag="PER06"/>

      </medi:segment>
    </medi:segment>
```

Comment: This is why I'm always suggesting a data translator.  You're kind of using a square peg for a round hole here.  Looping through the 837 can be daunting even with a decent mapping tool.  If you can't go with a mapping tool, I'd recommend flattening out the data as a middle step and then integrating.

Comment: Any suggestions on a good translator to use?  I have the xml loops and metadata documented Im just not sure of the syntax to handle loops.

Comment: There are quite a few good translators out there.  You won't find too much open source for X12.  I prefer the tools from Liaison for this kind of integration.